# Problems with connecting to mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql

Hi am trying to get data from php script in json. I get few errors: first is variable is not resolved. If I try to add new variable like below, then after running app I get error which says Error with converting. It's mainly a tutorial code but there as I said before is a problem with IS variable. Can you help me?

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));
  InputSteam is = null;

  //http post
  try{
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ik.su.lt/~jbarzelis/bandymas/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php");
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          InputStream is = entity.getContent();
  }catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
  }
  //convert response to string
  try{
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
          }
          is.close();

          result=sb.toString();
  }catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
  }

  //parse json data
  try{
          JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
          for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                  JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                          ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                          ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                          ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                  );
          }
  }
  catch(JSONException e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: First you have to ask a question.

Comment: Question would be How to fix it or what I missing. But I think it is already understandable.

Comment: Please post actual error messages, or spend more time explaining your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the simple typo in the `InputStream` declaration might be a place to start.

Comment: It realy helped. I simple inserted InputStream is = null; (as in the code above). But this time i deleted InputStream which is next to is = entity.getContent();  Thanks.